# How can I improve memory management on Qt Text fields for big texts?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qml

I am trying to build a log analysis tool using C++/QML using a MVC architecture. I'd like to keep the Model part in the C++ world, uncoupled to the Qt/QML world.

I wrote a simple app to open a file, read it in my Model and feed back the contents to the Controller, which feeds them to a TextArea as its "text". Just by opening a 5MB text file, as soon as the TextArea is starting to get populated, the application comes up to 3.3GB in memory usage and becomes unusable.

**C++/Qt:**

```
 //log->getContent returns a std::string
 logDisplayView->setProperty("text", QVariant(log->getContent().c_str()));
```

**Qml:**

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

    TextArea {
        id: logDisplayView
        objectName: "logDisplayView"
        readOnly: true;
    }
```

I'd like to make better use of the memory, but after days of research I haven't found any way of doing so. Is there any way to get Qt to let me manage the contents of the text field? Maybe in a similar way as how iOS/Swift's TableViewController utilizes your controller to load data as you scroll up and down.

**Edit:**

Printing the size of the log content comes out to 5MB:

```
qDebug() << "File length: " << strlen(log->getContent().c_str());
File length:  5031690
```

**Edit2**

logDisplayView is a *QObject, found with the following code:

```
if (engine.rootObjects().length() > 0) {    
    QObject *mainSplitView = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QObject*>("mainSplitView");
    if (mainSplitView) {

        QObject *logDisplayView = mainSplitView->findChild<QObject*>("logDisplayView");
        if (logDisplayView) {        
            fileHandler->setLogDisplayView(logDisplayView);
        }
    }
}
```

Where fileHandler is a class I created in which the C++/Qt code in the original question resides.

Comment: If 5MB of data blows up to more than 3GB then you are doing something seriously wrong beyond just using Qt/QML.

Comment: Can you do me a favour and just perform a strlen() operation on log->getContent().c_str() to prove to us that the length of the string is what you say?

Comment: I was also surprised, but running "qDebug() << "File length: " << strlen(log->getContent().c_str())" produces: "File length:  5031690 "

Comment: What's the `logDisplayView` object in C++? (Lookup by "id" in QML file is non-trivial, so I wonder how you got it). Also is that the TextArea from Qt Quick Controls 1 or 2? And are you positive that the 3GB come from *that* and not something else?

Comment: @peppe I added the info on the description. If I run the program, read the contents of the file and don't pass it to "logDisplayView->setProperty", memory stays at ~50MB. If I call it, it comes up to 3.3GB.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you use a "Text" element, with the text format set to plain text?